# Javascript, Web Page Not Calling Function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a basic form, and I am trying to make some event listeners come up if you click away without answering, but my webpage is not seeming to call the function and I do not know why. As of right now it will just submit even if nothing is actually typed in. I have also tried to put the call for the script at the top of the HTML page with a "defer" and at the bottom but it still wont load

```js
function resetProfile(e) {
  //document.forms[0].reset(); //no need to reset the form event by default clears input
  fNameError.innerHTML = '';
  lNameError.innerHTML = '';
  addressError.innerHTML = '';
  provinceError.innerHTML = '';
  countryError.innerHTML = '';
  emailError.innerHTML = '';
  phoneError.innerHTML = '';
  usernameError.innerHTML = '';
  passwordError.innerHTML = '';
}

function validateProfile(e) {

  var valid = true;

  //display warning if firstName is not entered
  if (profile.firstName.value === "") {
    fNameError.innerHTML = 'Please enter a First Name';
    valid = false;
  }

  //display warning if lastName is not entered
  if (profile.lastName.value === "") {
    lNameError.innerHTML = 'Please enter a Last Name';
    valid = false;
  }

  //display warning if address1 is not entered
  if (profile.address.value === "") {
    address1Error.innerHTML = 'Please enter address ';
    valid = false;
  }

  //display warning if city is not entered
  if (profile.province.value === "") {
    provinceError.innerHTML = 'Please enter a province';
    valid = false;
  }

  //display warning if province is not selected
  if (profile.country.value === "") {
    countryError.innerHTML = 'Please enter a Country';
    valid = false;
  }

  //display warning if country is not selected
  if (profile.email.value === "") {
    emailError.innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid email';
    valid = false;
  }

  if (profile.phone.value === "") {
    phoneError.innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid email';
    valid = false;
  }

  if (profile.username.value === "") {
    usernameError.innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid email';
    valid = false;
  }

  if (profile.password.value === "") {
    passwordError.innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid email';
    valid = false;
  }

  if (!valid) {
    // Then we prevent the form from being submitted/sent by canceling the event
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  //else alert("Thank you");
  return valid;

};



//form element events

//clear the warning message when the firstName is entered

document.querySelector('#fName').addEventListener("blur", function() {
  if (this.value !== "") {
    fNameError.innerHTML = "";
  }
});

//clear the warning message when the lastName is entered

document.querySelector('#lName').addEventListener("blur", function() {
  if (this.value !== "") {
    lNameError.innerHTML = "";
  }
});

//clear the warning message when the address1 is entered

document.querySelector('#address').addEventListener("blur", function() {
  if (this.value !== "") {
    addressError.innerHTML = "";
  }
});



document.querySelector('#province').addEventListener("blur", function() {
  if (this.value !== "") {
    provinceError.innerHTML = "";
  }
});


document.querySelector('#country').addEventListener("blur", function() {
  if (this.value !== "") {
    countryError.innerHTML = "";
  }

});

document.querySelector('#email').addEventListener("blur", function() {
  if (this.value !== "") {
    emailError.innerHTML = "";
  }

});

document.querySelector('#phone').addEventListener("blur", function() {
  if (this.value !== "") {
    phoneError.innerHTML = "";
  }

});

document.querySelector('#username').addEventListener("blur", function() {
  if (this.value !== "") {
    usernameError.innerHTML = "";
  }

});

document.querySelector('#password').addEventListener("blur", function() {
  if (this.value !== "") {
    passwordError.innerHTML = "";
  }

});



//Add a submit event listener to the form to invoke the validateProfile() method when the form submi           
document.profile.addEventListener("submit", validateProfile);

//Add a reser event listener to the form to invoke the resetProfile() method when the form is reset
document.profile.addEventListener("reset", resetProfile)
```

```html
<form name="profile">
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstName" value="FirstName"><br><br>
  <span class="alert" id="fNameError"></span>

  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastName" value="Last Name"><br><br>
  <span class="alert" id="lNameError"></span>

  <input type="text" id="address" name="address" value="Address"><br><br>
  <span class="alert" id="addressError"></span>

  <input type="text" id="Province" name="province" value="Province"><br><br>
  <span class="alert" id="provinceError"></span>

  <input type="text" id="country" name="country" value="Country"><br><br>
  <span class="alert" id="countryError"></span>

  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="Email"><br><br>
  <span class="alert" id="emailerror"></span>

  <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" value="Phone Number"><br><br>
  <span class="alert" id="phoneError"></span>

  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="Username"><br><br>
  <span class="alert" id="usernameError"></span>

  <input type="password" id="pwd" name="password" value="Password"><br><br>
  <span class="alert" id="passwordError"></span>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit"><input type="reset" value="Reset">


</form>
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use the `required` attribute if only checking for empty input?

Comment: Your snippet gives very clear error messages

Comment: Where are variables such as `fNameError` defined?

Comment: e.preventDefault() not event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many issues

IDs not correct

values are not empty because you should have used placeholder etc

event.preventDefault vs e.preventDefault

DRY: Don't repeat yourself - we could shorten this even more with consistent fieldnames

This works. Adding required to the fields would have been simpler

```js
const resetAlerts = () => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".alert").forEach(span => span.classList.add("hide"));
};

const validateProfile = (e) => {
  resetAlerts()
  let valid = true;
  
  //display warning if firstName is not entered
  if (document.getElementById('fname').value === "") {
    document.getElementById('fNameError').classList.remove("hide")
    valid = false;
  }

  //display warning if lastName is not entered
  if (document.getElementById('lname').value === "") {
    document.getElementById('lNameError').classList.remove("hide")
    valid = false;
  }

  //display warning if address1 is not entered
  if (document.getElementById('address').value === "") {
    document.getElementById('addressError').classList.remove("hide")
    valid = false;
  }

  //display warning if city is not entered
  if (document.getElementById('province').value === "") {
    document.getElementById('provinceError').classList.remove("hide")
    valid = false;
  }

  //display warning if province is not selected
  if (document.getElementById('country').value === "") {
    document.getElementById('countryError').classList.remove("hide")
    valid = false;
  }

  //display warning if country is not selected
  if (document.getElementById('email').value === "") {
    document.getElementById('emailError').classList.remove("hide")
    valid = false;
  }

  if (document.getElementById('phone').value === "") {
    document.getElementById('phoneError').classList.remove("hide")
    valid = false;
  }

  if (document.getElementById('username').value === "") {
    document.getElementById('usernameError').classList.remove("hide")
    valid = false;
  }

  if (document.getElementById('pwd').value === "") {
    document.getElementById('passwordError').classList.remove("hide")
    valid = false;
  }

  if (!valid) {
    // Then we prevent the form from being submitted/sent by canceling the event
    e.preventDefault();
  }

};




//Add a submit event listener to the form to invoke the validateProfile() method when the form submi           
document.getElementById("profile").addEventListener("submit", validateProfile);

//Add a reser event listener to the form to invoke the resetProfile() method when the form is reset
document.getElementById("profile").addEventListener("reset", resetAlerts);
```

```css
span.alert.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="profile">
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstName" placeholder="FirstName">
  <span class="alert hide" id="fNameError">Please enter a First Name</span><br><br>

  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
  <span class="alert hide" id="lNameError">Please enter a Last Name</span><br><br>

  <input type="text" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Address">
  <span class="alert hide" id="addressError">Please enter address</span><br><br>

  <input type="text" id="province" name="province" placeholder="Province">
  <span class="alert hide" id="provinceError">Please enter a province</span><br><br>

  <input type="text" id="country" name="country" placeholder="Country">
  <span class="alert hide" id="countryError">Please enter a Country</span><br><br>

  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  <span class="alert hide" id="emailError">Please enter a valid email</span><br><br>

  <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
  <span class="alert hide" id="phoneError">Please enter a valid phone number</span><br><br>

  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
  <span class="alert hide" id="usernameError">Please enter a valid username</span><br><br>

  <input type="password" id="pwd" name="password" placeholder="Password">
  <span class="alert hide" id="passwordError">Please enter a valid password</span><br><br>

  <input type="submit" placeholder="Submit"><input type="reset" placeholder="Reset" id="reset">


</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple errors regarding naming of id. Like `lName` in JS but `lname` in HTML or `pwd` in JS and `password` in HTML. Also because you're only checking against empty fields you could use the [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) HTML attribute.

Also you should put the
`event.preventDefault();` at the start of the method. Just to be sure that your code is used. Oh and it is `e.preventDefault()` as `e` is the parameter name in `function validateProfile(e)`.

```js
function resetProfile(e) {
  //document.forms[0].reset(); //no need to reset the form event by default clears input
   fNameError.innerHTML = '';
   lNameError.innerHTML = '';
   addressError.innerHTML = '';
   provinceError.innerHTML = '';
   countryError.innerHTML = '';
   emailError.innerHTML = '';
   phoneError.innerHTML = '';
   usernameError.innerHTML = '';
   passwordError.innerHTML = '';
}

function validateProfile(e) {
// Then we prevent the form from being submitted/sent by canceling the event
    e.preventDefault(); // It is e not event. put it here to make sure your code is used
var valid = true;

//display warning if firstName is not entered
if (profile.firstName.value === "") {
    fNameError.innerHTML = 'Please enter a First Name';
    valid = false;
}

//display warning if lastName is not entered
if (profile.lastName.value === "") {
    lNameError.innerHTML = 'Please enter a Last Name';
    valid = false;
}

//display warning if address1 is not entered
if (profile.address.value === "") {
    address1Error.innerHTML = 'Please enter address ';
    valid = false;
}

//display warning if city is not entered
if (profile.province.value === "") {
    provinceError.innerHTML = 'Please enter a province';
    valid = false;
}

//display warning if province is not selected
if (profile.country.value === "") {
    countryError.innerHTML = 'Please enter a Country';
    valid = false;
}

     //display warning if country is not selected
if (profile.email.value === "") {
   emailError.innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid email';
    valid = false;
}

if (profile.phone.value === "") {
    phoneError.innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid email';
    valid = false;
}

if (profile.username.value === "") {
    usernameError.innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid email';
    valid = false;
}

if (profile.password.value === "") {
    passwordError.innerHTML = 'Please enter a valid email';
    valid = false;
}
};



//form element events

//clear the warning message when the firstName is entered

document.querySelector('#fname').addEventListener("blur", function(){
  if (this.value !== ""){
    fNameError.innerHTML = "";
}
});

//clear the warning message when the lastName is entered

// It is lname not lName
document.querySelector('#lname').addEventListener("blur", function(){
if (this.value !== ""){
    lNameError.innerHTML = "";
}
});

//clear the warning message when the address1 is entered

document.querySelector('#address').addEventListener("blur", function(){
if (this.value !== ""){
    addressError.innerHTML = "";
}
});



document.querySelector('#province').addEventListener("blur", function(){
if (this.value !== ""){
    provinceError.innerHTML = "";
}
  });


document.querySelector('#country').addEventListener("blur", function(){
if (this.value !== ""){
    countryError.innerHTML = "";
}

});

document.querySelector('#email').addEventListener("blur", function(){
if (this.value !== ""){
    emailError.innerHTML = "";
}

   });

document.querySelector('#phone').addEventListener("blur", function(){
if (this.value !== ""){
    phoneError.innerHTML = "";
}

});

document.querySelector('#username').addEventListener("blur", function(){
if (this.value !== ""){
    usernameError.innerHTML = "";
}

});

// It is pwd in html and it should be here
document.querySelector('#pwd').addEventListener("blur", function(){
if (this.value !== ""){
    passwordError.innerHTML = "";
}

});



//Add a submit event listener to the form to invoke the validateProfile() method when the form submi           
document.profile.addEventListener("submit", validateProfile);

//Add a reser event listener to the form to invoke the resetProfile() method when the form is reset
document.profile.addEventListener("reset", resetProfile)
```

```html
<form name = "profile">
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstName"  value = "FirstName" required><br><br>
      <span class="alert" id="fNameError"></span>
    
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastName" value = "Last Name" required><br><br>
      <span class="alert" id="lNameError"></span>

      <input type="text" id="address" name="address" value = "Address" required><br><br>
        <span class="alert" id="addressError"></span>

      <input type="text" id="province" name="province" value= "Province" required><br><br>
      <span class="alert" id="provinceError"></span>

      <input type="text" id="country" name="country" value = "Country" ><br><br>
      <span class="alert" id="countryError"></span>

      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value = "Email"><br><br>
      <span class="alert" id="emailerror"></span>

      <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone"  value = "Phone Number"><br><br>
      <span class="alert" id="phoneError"></span>

      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value = "Username"><br><br>
      <span class="alert" id="usernameError"></span>
      
      <input type="password" id="pwd" name="password" value = "Password"><br><br> 
      <span class="alert" id="passwordError"></span>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit"><input type="reset" value="Reset">

     
    </form>
```

Comment: You missed a few :) Also value should be placeholder or all fields are filled - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66769319/295783)

Comment: @mplungjan didn't want to make it copy paste for the OP. I mean I think the OP would learn more from figuring it out on their own with the help of some suggestions of where to look